# ¿Cómo modificar una función para que pueda remover un evento cada vez que se ejecute otra función?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo podría modificar *agregarvalidacionfechahotel2* para que pueda remover el evento *changeDate* cada vez que se ejecute la función *eliminarfilahotel*?

Intenté muchas formas de remover el evento desde afuera de la función *agregarvalidacionfechahotel* o *agregarvalidacionfechahotel2* y no pude.

```js
var contenedorhotelTransporte = document.getElementById('transportehotelContainer');
var botonAñadirHotel = document.getElementById('btnAñadirHotel');


function agregarFilaTransporteHotel() {


    var nuevaFila = document.createElement('div');
    nuevaFila.className = 'row';


    var indice = contenedorhotelTransporte.children.length + 2;


    nuevaFila.innerHTML = `
    <div class="col-sm">
        <input type="text" id="ciudaddestinohotel${indice}" name="ciudaddestinohotel${indice}" placeholder="Destino"
            class="input-city" autocomplete="off" onchange="setFocus('fechapartidahotel${indice}')" /><br>
        <input type="text" id="citycodedestinohotel${indice}" class="back-input" readonly />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
        <input id="fechapartidahotel${indice}" type="text" placeholder="Check-in" class="input-calendar"
         readonly>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
        <input id="fecharetornohotel${indice}" type="text" placeholder="Check-out" class="input-calendar"
            onchange="setFocus('ciudaddestinohotel${indice + 1}')" readonly>
        <button class="btn-eliminarfila" onclick="eliminarFilaHotel(this)">Eliminar</button>
    </div>
    
`;


    contenedorhotelTransporte.appendChild(nuevaFila);


    if (contenedorhotelTransporte.children.length >= 6) {
        botonAñadirHotel.style.display = 'none';
    }




    var nuevoDatePickerInput2 = document.getElementById(`fecharetornohotel${indice - 1}`);

    var nuevoDatePickerInput = document.getElementById(`fechapartidahotel${indice}`);
    var nuevoDatePickerInputRetorno = document.getElementById(`fecharetornohotel${indice}`);
    var auxfechapartidavuelos1 = nuevoDatePickerInput2.datepicker.getDate();

    if (!auxfechapartidavuelos1) {
        auxfechapartidavuelos1 = new Date();
    }

    new Datepicker(nuevoDatePickerInput, {
        autohide: true,
        language: 'es',
        minDate: auxfechapartidavuelos1
    });

    new Datepicker(nuevoDatePickerInputRetorno, {
        autohide: true,
        language: 'es',
        minDate: dateToday
    });



    for (let i = 1; i <= indice; i++) {
        var datePickerInput = document.getElementById(`fecharetornohotel${i}`);
        var datePickerInputPartida = document.getElementById(`fechapartidahotel${i + 1}`);
        if (datePickerInput || datePickerInputPartida) {
            agregarValidacionFechaHotel(datePickerInput, i);
            agregarValidacionFechaHotel2(datePickerInputPartida, i);
        }
    }



    var nuevoDestinoAutocompleteInput = document.getElementById(`ciudaddestinohotel${indice}`);
    var destinoAutocompleteFile = `/searchbox/include/autoc-cdestinomulhotel${indice}.php`;
    ac.attach({
        target: nuevoDestinoAutocompleteInput,
        data: destinoAutocompleteFile
    });



}
```

Esta es una de las funciones a modificar:

```
function agregarValidacionFechaHotel(datePickerInput, indice) {
    datePickerInput.addEventListener('changeDate', function (e) {
        var siguienteDatePickerId = `fechapartidahotel${indice + 1}`;
        var siguienteCiudad = `ciudaddestinohotel${indice + 1}`;
        var siguienteDatePickerInput = document.getElementById(siguienteDatePickerId);

        if (siguienteDatePickerInput) {
            siguienteDatePickerInput.datepicker.destroy();

            var nuevaFechaPartidaVuelosActual = datePickerInput.datepicker.getDate();

            new Datepicker(siguienteDatePickerInput, {
                autohide: true,
                language: 'es',
                minDate: nuevaFechaPartidaVuelosActual
            });

            setFocus(siguienteCiudad);

        }
    });
}
```

Esta es otra de las funciones a modificar:

```
function agregarValidacionFechaHotel2(datePickerInput, indice) {
    datePickerInput.addEventListener('changeDate', function (e) {
        var siguienteDatePickerId = `fecharetornohotel${indice + 1}`;
        var siguienteDatePickerInput = document.getElementById(siguienteDatePickerId);

        if (siguienteDatePickerInput) {
            siguienteDatePickerInput.datepicker.destroy();

            var nuevaFechaPartidaVuelosActual = datePickerInput.datepicker.getDate();

            new Datepicker(siguienteDatePickerInput, {
                autohide: true,
                language: 'es',
                minDate: nuevaFechaPartidaVuelosActual
            });

            setFocus(siguienteDatePickerId);
        }

    });

    
}
```

En esta función *eliminarFilaHotel* es donde deberían quitarse los eventos de los campos *datePickerInput* y *datePickerInputPartida*:

```
function eliminarFilaHotel(botonEliminar) {
    var filaAEliminar = botonEliminar.closest('.row');
    contenedorhotelTransporte.removeChild(filaAEliminar);

    // Reordenar indices
    reordenarIndicesHotel();

    if (contenedorhotelTransporte.children.length < 6) {
        botonAñadirHotel.style.display = 'block';
    }

    establecerFechaMinimaEnFechasRestantesHotel();

    
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (let i = 1; i <= contenedorhotelTransporte.children.length; i++) {
            var datePickerInput = document.getElementById(`fecharetornohotel${i}`);
            var datePickerInputPartida = document.getElementById(`fechapartidahotel${i + 1}`);

            if (datePickerInput || datePickerInputPartida) {
                // Eliminar evento y volver a agregarlo

            }
        }
    }, 100);
}




function establecerFechaMinimaEnFechasRestantesHotel() {
    var fechaReferenciaId = 'fecharetornohotel1';
    var fechaReferenciaInput = document.getElementById(fechaReferenciaId);

    var filas = contenedorhotelTransporte.children;

    for (var i = 1; i <= filas.length; i++) {
        var fechaActualId = `fechapartidahotel${i + 1}`;
        var fechaActualInput = document.getElementById(fechaActualId);

        if (fechaReferenciaInput && fechaActualInput) {
            fechaActualInput.datepicker.destroy();

            var nuevaFechaReferencia = fechaReferenciaInput.datepicker.getDate();

            if (!nuevaFechaReferencia) {
                nuevaFechaReferencia = new Date();
            }

            new Datepicker(fechaActualInput, {
                autohide: true,
                language: 'es',
                minDate: nuevaFechaReferencia
            });
        }
    }
}

var instanciasAutocompletado = {};


function reordenarIndicesHotel() {
    var filas = contenedorhotelTransporte.children;

    for (var i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
        var indice = i + 2;
        var campos = filas[i].querySelectorAll('input, select');

        campos.forEach(function (campo) {
            if (campo.id.includes('citycode')) {
                actualizarCampo(campo, 'citycode', indice);
            } else if (campo.id.includes('ciudaddestinohotel')) {
                actualizarCampo(campo, 'ciudaddestinohotel', indice);
                actualizarAutocompletado(campo, 'autoc-cdestinomulhotel', indice);
            } else {
                actualizarCampo(campo, '', indice);
            }
        });
    }

    console.log("Después de la actualización de índices3:");
    for (var i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
        var campos = filas[i].querySelectorAll('input, select');
        campos.forEach(function (campo) {
            console.log(campo.id, campo.value);
        });
    }
}
```

¿Cómo tendría que hacerlo para que pueda remover el evento al momento que se ejecute *eliminarfilahotel*?